Can an exchange retrieve tokens sent to the wrong token address?
I stupidly sent USDT from KuCoin to my Coinbase USDC address (on Solana network).
Is there an ability within Solana for an exchange to retrieve the tokens, as I can see them via the wallet address on SolScan.
I’ve essentially been told by Coinbase that it’s impossible to do it on Solana, but easy to do had it been sent via Eth etc.
